# What's the reason to add a symlink to /dev directory with udev rules?

Tags: kernel-modules, udev, devices

I understand that you can write custom udev rules to create a symlink in /dev directory.

But what is the use of having a symlink in /dev?

What is the symlink linking to?

I know you can interact with regular links in the /dev directory but not understanding what a symlink does.

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb"`

Comment: Why do you ordinarily use symbolic links? I assume it is to access a file or directory using a different name.

Comment: Yes, that's why I ordinarily use them, however if you look very carefully at the udev rule I posted there's no co-oresponding mapping directory to the defined symlink. What does symlink field map to and why is it needed?

Comment: Is your question: What is a symlink?

Comment: Just realized that the title of my question could be improved. Edit: improved

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically it's to give a known fixed pathname to access the device; `/dev/mydevice` is fixed but depending on the order things are plugged in it might be `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyUSB1` or `/dev/ttyUSB2` or...

This can be useful for devices which can present multiple endpoints; eg I have a USB HUBZ device that presents zigbee and zwave endpoints.  These rules create easy to use names

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{interface}=="HubZ Z-Wave Com Port", SYMLINK+="zwave"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{interface}=="HubZ ZigBee Com Port", SYMLINK+="zigbee"
```

In my case I also have multiple printers and so the rule

```
#Rules for Terow printer
KERNEL=="lp*" ATTRS{idVendor}=="0416", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5011", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="lp_receipt"
```

Now I can just do `cat file > /dev/lp_receipt` and it will print and I don't need to know if it's really `/dev/usb/lp0` or `/dev/usb/lp1`.

The symlimk created points to the "real" entry;

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Sep  8 12:17 /dev/lp_receipt -> usb/lp1
```